# Ag-grid Angular:custom header is not detecting touch

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I am new in ag-grid, I am using ag-grid in the angular5+ app. 
I have implemented a custom column level filter by implementing IHeaderAngularComp interface. it's working fine in desktop/laptop. but it's not working in touch devices like iPad/mobile etc.
it seems to the header is not detecting touch event.

In the custom header, I implemented an input text box. it's working fine in desktop but when I use touch device iPad/mobile, the input box gets disable.
ag-Grid version: X.X.X
"ag-grid": "15.0.0",
"ag-grid-angular": "15.0.0"
Angular version: 5.1.2

//custom-header.component.html

```
<div>
<a class="btn btn-sm text-truncate py-0" [ngStyle]="{'width':'98%'}" (click)="sortBy($event)">
    <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-sort-desc': currentOrder=='desc', 'fa-sort-asc': currentOrder=='asc'}"
        [hidden]="!currentOrder"></i>
    <span>{{params.displayName}}</span>
</a>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm pl-2" [ngStyle]="{'width':'90%'}" *ngIf="params.bISActiveForFilter">
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm align-self-center filterTxtBox py-0" name="search"
        (keyup.enter)="onEnterPress($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchText">
    <span class="input-group-btn filterTxtClsBtn" [hidden]="!searchText">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm py-0" (click)="clearColFilter($event)"><i
                class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

And from the parent component, I'm calling custom-header component as below
  `columnDef.headerComponentFramework = CustomHeaderComponent;`